# GA4 setup for multiple sites with the same structure

Tags: google-analytics-4

What is the best way to set up GA4 for the following Use Case:

- an ecommerce company has a multiple websites for different countries
- the sites are structured in the same way and tracking is being set from one team for all the countries
- the countries get access only to their own data
- data from the different countries does not need to be reported together

Currently tracking is set up with Adobe Analytics and we use different report suits for the countries, but the tracking is managed from one Tag Manager (Launch) so when we make changes, define new eVars etc they apply automatically to all countires.
I have never worked with google analytics so it is a bit confusing to understand how google handles this type of setup. Goal is to minimise maintaining the same change accross multiple countries' domains.

My research so far points to setting up different properties for the different countries, but how does the setting up of custom events, dimensions, metrics etc work?